# Does python support sub orchestration in Azure durable functions?

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm writing a service, and within it I have the need for sub orchestrators in my parent orchestrator. Now I know this is supported in javascript and C# [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-sub-orchestrations?tabs=csharp), however i'm wondering if it's possible in python, either through an external package or just some hidden usage.

Comment: Well if anyone has the same question, it looks like it's been added in this [pr](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-python/issues/62), however the doc's just haven't been updated yet.

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Python support for Durable Functions is currently in public preview**. The following are the current known limitations.

·**Sub-orchestrations are not yet supported** (planned [#62](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-python/issues/62))

·Durable Entities are not yet supported (not yet planned #96)

For more details, you could refer to this [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-python).